Basic Authentication doesn't work while using Postman but works on browser
My spring boot web application works fine using browser. When i try to access any URL in my application without loggin application forwards me to login page and when i login i can succesfully access all URLs as i should be. Authentication works fine on browser but when i send GET or any other request to URLs using postman(of course i am providing username and password chosing basic authentication) it always forwards me back to login page.
Here is my security config

package com.SocialApp.myapp.config;

import com.SocialApp.myapp.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.HttpSecurityDsl;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@Configuration
//integrate spring security with mvc
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration{

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

     @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
     @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider auth = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        auth.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        auth.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return auth;
    }


    //auth changed after spring security 6.1, WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is depreciated
    @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.requestMatchers(
                new AntPathRequestMatcher("/registration**"),
                new AntPathRequestMatcher("/js/**"),
                new AntPathRequestMatcher("/css/**"),
                new AntPathRequestMatcher("/img/**")).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin(login -> login.loginPage("/login").permitAll())
                .logout(logout -> logout
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .permitAll());
        http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);


        return http.build();
    }

}


Seems like there was a mistake i use form based authenticaiton which is not supported by postman

Then please remove answer and question.

It works in postman too. Just choose basic auth from auth type dropdown list in Authorization tab.
